# Running a Docker container from a Jenkins pipeline, and capture the output

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkinsfile, how can I run a Docker container and capture the output, without reverting to `sh` instructions?

This is how I build my container image during the `Build` stage:

```
dockerImage = docker.build(env.DOCKER_COORDS, "--build-arg BUILD_VERSION=${env.BUILD_VERSION} .")
```

And this is how I push the image in a later `Publish` stage:

```
withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: env.DOCKER_REG_CREDS_ID) {
    dockerImage.push('latest')
}
```

In between the `Build` and `Publish` stages, in a `Test` stage, I would like to validate that the output from the container, when passing a `--version` argument, is equal to `${env.BUILD_VERSION}`.

How can I run the container and capture the output, without having to use `sh "docker ..."` instructions again?

Answer (score 2):

I am new to this but according to the [documentation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow) of Docker Pipeline plugin, you can use `Image.run([args])`, for your case it will be `dockerImage.run()`

To pass environment variables:

`dockerImage.run(['-e your_variable=X'])`

Comment: And then how would I get the output from that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you need to make sure that a certain environment variable is present, not that you absolutely want to capture it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can run and capture the output using the `sh` method (on a Linux slave and `bat` for windows). For example, to retrieve the python version of the official python docker, it will look like this:

```
def version = sh label: '', returnStdout: true, script: 'docker run python python --version'
```

And then you could just compare the output of the commande with `${env.BUILD_VERSION}`. This shouldn't be to different with your docker image.

Comment: Yes, I have done that also in the past. But now I'm using the `docker.build` command, instead of relying on shell commands. So I would like to understand how to invoke the Docker container given the approach that I use.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it explicit that 'sh' should not be used.